# Postman - Possible to check Runner input file to dynamically create body?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm frequently using Postman to send requests to a Kanban API. However, the data being sent isn't always the same.

For example, the body of the request will always have an ID for the Kanban card to be added to the board, `{{External_Card_ID}}`, but it won't always have a plannedFinish or a title.

```
{
    "customId": "{{External_Card_ID}}",
    "title": "{{Title}}",
    "plannedFinish": "{{Due_Date}}"
}
```

Is it possible to use pre-request scripts in Postman to check the CSV given to the runner to say something like

```
requestBody = "{

"customId":"{{External_Card_ID}}""

}"

If csvInput contains "Title" column then

append ",title":"{{Title}}" to requestBody
```

And then set the body to `{{requestBody}}`?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. How about you check the documentation and how to code Javascript. This question is way too generic/ broad, please specify what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: Extremely helpful comment. Thanks so much. Solved

Comment: Please also check the guidelins for asking questions. A said, the question is way too generic/ broad, you thus should have specified what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: I would argue that with the pseudo code it was clear I didn't know the syntax for grabbing data from the input CSV through JavaScript in Postman. Not really any need to suggest someone doesn't know JavaScript based off one specific use-case. A little reading comprehension goes a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: use `data.ColumnName`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).